# How to subset standard deviations for each column after scale() function in R?

Tags: r

I have a data matrix that contains names of samples as columns and lists of genes as rows. After transposing the matrix and calculating the z-scores using the `scale()` function, I transposed my matrix back.

Now I'm interested in subsetting my dataframe. So for example, if Sample 1 has rows  that have values 2 standard deviations away from the mean, I would like to extract that rows and store it in a variable.

I've tried to `select()` my data frame however I'm getting this error message:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"matrix"

Additionally after transposing the matrix back, I'm unable to get column names.

I have also used the `abs()` function however it returns a `TRUE` and `FALSE` values, however I still get the same error message if I try to select columns based on if they are `TRUE` or not

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please consider adding a reproducible example to your question to allow others to recreate your problem and propose solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Something is seriously amiss if `abs()` returns a logical value. And you should use the term transform rather than "transpose". They are not synonyms.